# how can I post an external form using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, curl

External form

```
<form action="MyForm.action" method="post">
```

hosted on a different server.

I want my PHP script to post this form and display the results

How can I do this?

Comment: What does it mean to post a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To post a form from a PHP script you'd use cURL. Here is an example

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
  $fields = array(
    'lname'=>urlencode($last_name),
    'fname'=>urlencode($first_name),
  );

  //url-ify the data for the POST
  foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
  rtrim($fields_string,'&');

  // Initialize curl
  $ch = curl_init();

  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

  //execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // Results of post in $result
?>
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` should be a boolean `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields) > 0);`.  `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can be an array (you don't need to "url-ify" it) `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Let cURL do the URL-encoding!